# Global var is being reset by each for loop iteration instead of updating

Tags: javascript

**Disclosure:** I'm fairly new and inexperienced with JS, but I have spent hours trying to find a solution to this via Stackoverflow and other internet resources. My mentor is away this week, so I am hoping someone here will be able to help me. Thank you in advance!

**Intro:** I'm trying to keep track of a running total via variable setupTotal. I placed it at the top of the function getStoredData, thinking that it would act like a global and not be over-written or reset during the for loop within getStoredData. I've included the surrounding code for context and bolded what I thought pertained to the actual issue I'm having.

**The Issue:** Every time the for loop cycles though an iteration, my setupTotal variable is being reset. I see this both in the console log and in the setupFees.innerHTML at the end of the buildSetup function. From what I understand, when I specify var setupTotal = 0; at the beginning of the getStoredData function, the updates I'm making in the buildSetup nested function should be over-writing the original value. Yet, each time a new iteration runs, the setupTotal value is starting at 0 again.

---

```
function getStoredData() {

    // Builds "Service Row" div to house the incoming content
    buildDivRow();

    var setupTotal = 0;

    // Loops through the boxes to see what's stored
    for (var service in serviceDatabase) {

        for (id=0; id < serviceDatabase[service].length; id++) {

        console.log("Starting " + service + ": " + serviceDatabase[service][id]);

            // Get the stored data if it exists
            var inputID = service + "-input-" + id;
            var getData = localStorage.getItem(inputID);
            console.log("Attempting data retrieval for " + inputID + ": " + getData);

            // Passes the info to a function that creates the HTML to display stored data
            if (getData != null) {

                // Passes the info to functions that captures "total" data
                console.log("buildSetup starting, service: " + service);
                console.log("buildSetup starting, getData: " + getData);
                console.log("buildSetup starting, setupTotal): " + setupTotal);
                buildSetup(service, getData, setupTotal);

                // Passes the info to a function that builds the div containers
                buildDivXs12(getData, inputID, service, id);

                // Logs that the data was found successfully or not
                console.log("Retrieved ID (" + inputID + ") and data (" + getData + ")");
            } else {
                console.log("No data to retrieve for " + serviceDatabase[service][id] + ": " + inputID );
            }
        }
    }
}

// Keeps track of the setup fees
function buildSetup(service, getData, setupTotal) {

    // Retrieve the setup fee
    var setup = setupDatabase[service][getData];
    console.log("buildSetup ending, setup: " + setup);

    // Update the setupTotal global var
    setupTotal = parseInt(setupTotal) + parseInt(setup);
    console.log("buildSetup ending, setupTotal): " + setupTotal);

    // Update the setupFees inner HTML
    var setupFees = document.getElementById("setupFee");
    setupFees.innerHTML = setupTotal;
}
```

Comment: Does it really have ** on some line of your code? Does it not throw any error on your end?

Comment: @ChristianEsperar That is **bold** effect (since it's a code snippett the `**` won't be processed by the markdown)!

Comment: `setupTotal` is not global! It only visible within the scope of `getStoredData`.

Comment: Without the data you are using (in it's appropriate structures) there is no way to answer this.  `setupTotal` is calculated from `setup` which is in turn calculated from a property of some object called `setupDatabase`. We have no values for any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your code, what you can do is return the **setupTotal** value on **buildSetup** function then assign it after it's called on your **getStoredData** function like this:

```
function getStoredData() {
  ..
  console.log("buildSetup starting, setupTotal): " + setupTotal);
  setupTotal = buildSetup(service, getData, setupTotal);
  ..
}

function buildSetup(service, getData, setupTotal) {
  ..
  setupFees.innerHTML = setupTotal;

  return setupTotal;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that embedded functions would still have access to high-level variables, as long as they were still within the scope of the parent-level function. Is there an easy explanation you can give me as to why the var setupTotal doesn't get updated with the way I had it set up?

Comment: Yup right, you can access the **setupTotal** within **getStoredData** since you're on the same scope but the problem on your code is, you always assign **setupTotal** to **0** everytime you call **getStoredData**.

If you put the **setupTotal** in root level of you script, it will retain the value on it but I think there still some computation problem occured when you do this base on your current code

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to go through this with me. I'll do a little more research. Thanks!